# Authentication in Outlook 365 api

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, office365api, outlook-restapi

My use case is: make a script that will run every hour to extract information about a user's calendar.

My script runs in Python and I get a token but I am unable to get the user's events. I have registered my app in the [Microsoft Application Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com) and given the Calendar.read application permission. An administrator gave consent by accessing the `/adminconsent` endpoint.

Here is my code to get the token (documentation [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service)):

```
url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token'
data = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': app_id,
    'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',  <--- Really not sure about this here
    'client_secret': client_secret,
}
r = requests.post(url, data=data)
token = r.json().get('access_token')
```

What scope am I suppose to use? The documentation only speaks of the one above.

And to read the user's calendar:

```
url = 'https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/users/{}/events'.format(user_email)
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(token)
}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

I am not sure of the  `users/{user_email}/` part.

I get an access token but I get the following error when trying to read the user's calendar:

> Response [401]
>
> The access token is acquired using an authentication method that is too weak to allow access for this application. Presented auth strength was 1, required is 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have finally found it. I was very close.

I had to use Microsoft Graph API endpoint instead of Outlook Unified API endpoint.

The final code looks like:

```
import requests

# Get a token
url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token'
data = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': app_id,
    'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
    'client_secret': client_secret,
}
r = requests.post(url, data=data)
token = r.json().get('access_token')

# ...

# Use the token using microsoft graph endpoints
url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{}/events'.format(user_email) # can also use the user_id (e.g. 12345-abcde-...)
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(token)
}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Microsoft's documentation really needs clarification. It has too many different APIs that do very similar things.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Fabrice. Graph is absolutely the recommended API to use. It actually uses the Outlook endpoint under the covers. We have a doc here that attempts to explain the difference and why you might choose one over the other: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/compare-graph-outlook. We are working on unifying the REST API story to be super-clear that Graph is the preferred way.

Comment: Cool. Thank you for your comment. I guess it's that point in time where you are trying to transition from one version to the other hence my last phrase.

Comment: I fully agree with your despair at Microsoft's documentation for this. There are no simple python example, only a Django server build tutorial...

Comment: Where app_id is your username? and client_secret is your password?

Comment: @partydog Hmm no? Not sure what you mean by username and password. But from what I remember, in your Microsoft Graph web view you can get your application identifier (app_id in my exemple) and generate a key to use in your code (client_secret).

Comment: This line:
`'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'`
needs a comma at the end